# Images not displaying carriwewave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4.1

```
Windows 8.1
Rails 4.1
Ruby 2.0
```

I have the CarrierWave

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  Cw_image_folder = '/agents/uploads/cw/'

  def store_dir
    "#{Cw_image_folder}#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

This is working for uploads and images as well as their various versions (thumb, small and medium) are stored in the defined store_dir.

The problem is that when I try to use the images, like this:

```
<img class="media-object" src="<%= @agent.avatar.current_path(:medium) if @agent.avatar? %>" alt="Image Not Found">
```

or this:

```
<img class="media-object" src="<%= @agent.avatar.url(:medium) if @agent.avatar? %>" alt="Image Not Found">
```

The image is not displayed. Searching through the logs, here's what I find:

```
Started GET "/images/C%3A/agents/uploads/cw/agent/avatar/36/thumb_img_1984.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-09 03:43:13 -0700
```

Why is the /images/C%3A added to the beginning?

Answer (score -1):

To store correct path in db, use this

`<%= image_tag @agent.avatar.url if @agent.avatar? %>`

Comment: How does this store a value in the DB? what I posted is a view syntax I am not storing the path in the DB, I am using the uploader to tell carrierwave where to find the file. Or are you saying that I should be adding a url field to the table? In that case, what's the point of the value in the uploader configuration file?